# How to change default USER Authorisation to custom model in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, authorization

I have model.py file which has one model named as Tutor

```
class Tutor(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I want to implement token authentication using this Tutor model, for login and signup. As of now I have setup token authentication and its working good, but its default authorisation is for USER, which get generated using **python manage.py createsuperuser**, and I want to use Tutor for Authroization.

How to go building this, any resources for my usecase would mean a lot :)

Comment: better solution is still to`authorizate users by user model`, and `give` to `user` field `status` which will represent who is this user, he might be `tutor` or `student` or `policeman`

Comment: It seems to be a great approach. But I have one issue, like for superuser the column field might different and for tutor or student or policeman the field might be different, how to go implementing about this ?

Comment: in this case create `class tutor`, `class policeman`, `class student` with field foreing_key `user` which assinged via foreing key to your `user` model. Here you could create diefferent fields for tutor, policeman and student , and still authorize them by one `user` model

Answer (score 0):

You can change your default auth model by updating the **AUTH_USER_MODEL = "<app_name>.<model_name>"** in settings.py

In your case, if your app name is User, it would be `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "User.Tutor"`